# How do I generate the multiplication table for GF(3^2)?

Tags: finite-field

I understood, how this works for arbitrary n and p = 2, but I am struggling with higher prime numbers as a base.
In the following, I wanted to use the irreducible polynomial `r(x) = x²+1 = 101`.

```
static const __flash uint8_t lookup[9][9] = {
  // 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22  

     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   // 0
     0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22,   // 1
     0,  2,  ?,  ?,  ?, ...               // 2
     ...

};
```

In this case the entry of `2 * 2` would be `4` which is equivalent to `10` using a base of `3`. `10 mod 101` to the base of `3` would be `-21` and that would be equivalent to `2` because `-21 + 10 + 10 + 10 = 2` (10 is equivalent to 3 in a base of 3). So the actual final result for this entry would be `2`.
 Is that correct or completely wrong?
I am struggling because if you would write these entries as polynomials, you would have:
 `0, 1, 2, x, x + 1, x + 2, 2x, 2x + 1, 2x + 2`
and if my guess from above is correct, then `2 * 2 = x and x mod x²+1 = 2` and this looks kind of wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if my guess from above is correct, then `2 * 2 = x and x mod x²+1 = 2` and this looks kind of wrong.

Not only does it look wrong, it is wrong.

If $GF(3)$, `2 * 2 = 1`, and that continues to be true even if you extend the field to $GF(3^2)$.

In general, multiplying by 2 is easy; we can just use the identity $2 \times a = (1 + 1) \times a = 1 \times a + 1 \times a = a + a$, for any $a$.

The one slighty tricky part is `10 * 10`; however, if we just use the polynomial reduction, we get $x \times x = x^2 \bmod x^2 + 1 = x^2 - (x^2 + 1) = 2$, so `10 * 10 = 2`.

With that in mind, we can complete every other multiplication operation using the distributive law, for example, $(x + 2) \times (2x + 1) = (x \times 2x) + (x \times 1) + (2 \times 2x) + (2 \times 1) = (2\cdot 2) + (x) + (x) + 2 = 2x$, that is, `12 * 21 = 20`